# Getting values from Custom AuthorizeAttribute being default

Tags: c#, authorize-attribute

I have the follow Custom AuthorizeAttribute:

```
public class SystemAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
   public Form PermissionForm { get; set; } //Enum

   public PermissionValue Permissions { get; set; }//Enum

   public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
   {                
      //Request is an Authenticated Method?
      if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated)
      {
                Debug.WriteLine("Test 1 " + PermissionForm);
           if (!CurrentUserHasPermissionForm(PermissionForm))
          {
              //Deny access code
          }
      }
   }
  //...
}
```

After Login method it redirects to Index page from HomeController. The problem is when use SystemAuthorize Attribute in my HomeController the Form value always come as 0 when it should be 4 (Content).

HomeController method:

```
[SystemAuthorize(PermissionForm = Form.CONTENT, Permissions = PermissionValue.VIEW)]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return this.View();
}
```

Login method:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("Account/Login")]
public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model, string url = "")
{
   var user= GetUserAccount(model);
   if (user == null)
   {
     ModelState.AddModelError("", "User not found!");
     return View(model);
   }
   else
   {
       FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.Sign, false);

       var authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, user.Sign, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(20), false, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user));

       var authCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket));
                HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
}
```

Form enum:

```
 public enum Form : short
    {
        PATIENT = 1,
        USERS = 2,
        MEDICE = 3,
        CONTENT = 4,
    }
```

**What I'm doing wrong or missing?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately Microsoft made this a bit confusing by combining `IAuthorizationFilter` with `Attribute` in the same class. The fact of the matter is that attributes cannot *do* anything except store meta-data.

The part of MVC that *reads* the attribute is the `IAuthorizationFilter` which through some MVC magic is registered with MVC automatically when you place `AuthorizeAttribute` (or a subclass) on a controller or action.

But the only way to actually read the meta-data from the attribute is to use Reflection. The meta-data is in the same class, *but not the same instance* of the class. The meta-data is in the `Attribute`, but the code that executes when the filter runs is in the `IAuthorizationFilter`, which is a separate instance of the same class.

```
public class SystemAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public Form PermissionForm { get; set; } //Enum

    public PermissionValue Permissions { get; set; }//Enum

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var actionDescriptor = httpContext.Items["ActionDescriptor"] as ActionDescriptor;
        if (actionDescriptor != null)
        {
            var authorizeAttribute = this.GetSystemAuthorizeAttribute(actionDescriptor);

            // If the authorization attribute exists
            if (authorizeAttribute != null)
            {
                // Run the authorization based on the attribute
                var form = authorizeAttribute.PermissionForm;
                var permissions = authorizeAttribute.Permissions;

                // Return true if access is allowed, false if not...
                if (!CurrentUserHasPermissionForm(form))
                {
                    //Deny access code
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        // Pass the current action descriptor to the AuthorizeCore
        // method on the same thread by using HttpContext.Items
        filterContext.HttpContext.Items["ActionDescriptor"] = filterContext.ActionDescriptor;
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
    }

    private SystemAuthorizeAttribute GetSystemAuthorizeAttribute(ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
    {
        SystemAuthorizeAttribute result = null;

        // Check if the attribute exists on the action method
        result = (SystemAuthorizeAttribute)actionDescriptor
            .GetCustomAttributes(attributeType: typeof(SystemAuthorizeAttribute), inherit: true)
            .SingleOrDefault();

        if (result != null)
        {
            return result;
        }

        // Check if the attribute exists on the controller
        result = (SystemAuthorizeAttribute)actionDescriptor
            .ControllerDescriptor
            .GetCustomAttributes(attributeType: typeof(SystemAuthorizeAttribute), inherit: true)
            .SingleOrDefault();

        return result;
    }
}
```

Note that `OnAuthorization` has some logic in it that you will need to support output caching and the part of the code that checks for `[AllowAnonymous]`, so you should not put your authorization check there, but in `AuthorizeCore`. But unfortunately, `AuthorizeCore` isn't passed the `ActionDescriptor` you need to check whether the attribute exists, so you need the above `httpContext.Items` hack to ensure it is passed into that method on the same thread.

The Reflection part becomes much more clear if you separate your `Attribute` into a different class from the `IAuthorizationFilter`, as in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32254851).

Comment: Thanks. I'd corrected this removing the `[SystemAuthorize]` Attribute from class declaration which had no value specified for Form attribute. But looking your code it seems the right way to do it. I'll try it!

Comment: That's a hole new level of over-complicating from Microsoft side.